# Is it possible to access a job's arguments in the before_enqueue callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I'd like to perform some initial argument validation in the `before_enqueue` callback so that I can raise problems if they exist at the time the job is enqueued.

This would allow me to give the user feedback about problems immediately, rather than have the job try to run, fail, then somehow get that feedback to the user.

I see [in the API documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_enqueue) that a job object is passed in to the callback, but it is unclear from the API doc and the [Rails Guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) how one gets the `perform` arguments from that object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little exploring in the REPL, I found that the `job` object that is passed in to the callback has an `arguments` accessor that is an array of the arguments.

With ordinary arguments, they'll be in the `arguments` array by position:

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(arg1, arg2); end

  before_enqueue { |job| puts job.arguments }
end

TestJob.perform_later(:foo, 'bar')
# [:foo, "bar"]
```

With named arguments, they are in a hash in the first position of the array:

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(arg1:, arg2:); end

  before_enqueue { |job| puts job.arguments }
end

TestJob.perform_later(arg1: :foo, arg2: 'bar')
# [{:arg1=>:foo, :arg2=>"bar"}]
```